# Filter array of objects by index

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to filter array of objects by index.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(list,index) in lists" v-bind:key="index"
    @dblclick="deleteNote(index)">
    {{list.note}    
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Lists gets filled with objects of `imp`

```
var lists = [];

var imp = {
  note: "bla",
  hinweis: "blub",
  showNotiz: false
};

deleteNote(i) {
  let arr = this.lists.filter(item =>
    item.note !== this.lists[i]
  );

  this.lists = arr;
}
```

Comment: First, note is a string and lists[i] is an object. Or can note be an object ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this will works

```
deleteNote(i) {
  this.lists = this.lists.filter((_, index) => index !== i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use second argument to the filter function.

```
let arr = this.lists.filter( (item, index) =>  
    item.note !== this.lists[index]
);
this.lists = arr;
```

> Here is MDN docs for [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the main problem is that i can't compare a String(item.note) to a index.

Comment: If we have objects inside `lists` variable with `note` key, we can very well achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you want to remove an item by index?

```
deleteNote(i) {
  this.lists.splice(i, 1);
}
```

The above snippet should modify the existing array and remove one element at the desired index.

[MDN: Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)